# How to copy the following text from input box?

Tags: html, input

I've got the following input box...

```
<input type="text" id="sharees" class="form_field_as">
```

and I'm using the following to attempt to capture what is typed..

```
var txt2 = $('input[class="form_field_as"]').serialize();
```

However, that doesn't seem to be working. it's returning `""`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You serialize a form, not an input :)

Comment: hmm, removing serialize is giving me a HTML object... now how would I print this in order to make sure it's working correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
var txt2 = $('input.form_field_as').val();
```

or by id

```
var txt2 = $('#sharees').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function(){
    $('input.form_field_as').keyup(function(){
        var txt2 = $('input.form_field_as').val();
        $('p').text(txt2);
    })
});
```

Your code is wrong. That type of writing is used for other attributes. For an id use `#` and for a class use `.`.

http://jsfiddle.net/borayeris/qGT4W/1/

Comment: didn't work :( just to clarify.. this input is inside an `iframe` with the code in a listener `$(document).keypress(function(event){`